# Passing non-predetermined object into a method as parameter

Tags: java

I am experimenting with java a little bit and I ran into a problem with passing an object.
As I am mostly oriented on scripting languages, there are no problems with types and so on.

here in JAVA, I have some objects, that defines RESTful Client, every object is defined for one table, but all of them have some same methods.

My question is:
Is in java possible to have one method, that calls a method of passed object?

this is the piece of code:

```
ClientA ca;
ClientA cb;

public void main(String[] args){
ca = new ClientA();
cb = new ClientB();

callCount(ca);
}

public void callCount(Object o){
System.out.println("count of "+o.getName()+" is:"+o.countREST());
}
```

This is pretty much possible in scripting languages, but here, the IDE shouts, that he does not know the method of Object o.

Now, I know, that this is issue of type coversion, as the code has to know the type of object before calling its method.

Maybe a generic VAR would work, but I do not have Java 10 (March 2018), and for reasons I have to use Java 9.

So the question is obvious: Is here any nice way (and by nice I mean some oneliner or some generic conversion, not ugly if, switch or sth like that), how to pass non-predetermined object into method and force the program to run the method? Of course, there sould be try/catch block to be sure, that the passed object actually has this method, but that is my responsibility.

Or this is impossible and I have to copypaste methods for each type of object?

Comment: sorry, typo, but well, this will not compile anyway, it is not a valid java code, it has only demonstration purpose. for text, that is below the code

Comment: No, Java doesn't support duck typing. You'll have to define a common interface that supports the behaviors you plan on using within that method (`getName()` & `countREST()`), use that type for the parameter of your method, then for any object you want to pass into that method, have the type for that object implement the interface.

Comment: You'll need a common supertype -- either an interface or an abstract class -- that declares the methods avialable to use.

Answer (score 0):

What you should try is to use an interface. Make an interface that all of your objects wih the desired method will impliment. Then you can call the method from that function regardless of the object, as long as it `implements DesiredInterface`

Something like this:

```
interface IFoo() { /*Methods*/ }
```

Then

```
class Foo implements IFoo() {  /*Yata yata*/ }
```

Comment: Lorem isn't typically used for a placeholder in code, and it may confuse those reading it. Instead, developers typically use `Foo/Bar`, or try to use an identifier that best describes the type. It's great for literature & web dev, but in this case, it's pretty cryptic.

Comment: @VinceEmigh thanks! I was trying to remember which word people used but I couldn’t remember what the word is. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

You could do something like :

```
public void callCount(Object o){
    if(o instanceof Client A){
        System.out.println("count of "+ ((ClientA) o.getName()+" is:"+ (ClientA) o.countREST());
    }

}
```

**Use an abstract class**

If you have somewhat of an idea of the classes you are going to pass in, and they share some of the same functionality, you could do something like this:

```
public class BaseClass{

    public void getName(){
        //do something
    }

    public void countREST(){
        //do something
    }
}



public class ClientA extends BaseClass{

}

public class ClientB extends BaseClass{

}

public void main(String[] args){
ca = new ClientA();
cb = new ClientB();

callCount(ca);
}

public void callCount(BaseClass o){
     System.out.println("count of "+o.getName()+" is:"+o.countREST());
}
```

**User an interface**

If they didn't share functionality and you wanted each of the classes to handle their own implementation, you could do:

```
public interface BaseClass{

    public void getName();

    public void countREST();
}



public class ClientA implements BaseClass{
    @Override
    public void getName(){
        //Do ClientA GetName
    }

    @Override
    public void countREST(){
        //Do ClientA countREST
    }
}

public class ClientB implements BaseClass{
    @Override
    public void getName(){
        //Do ClientB GetName
    }

    @Override
    public void countREST(){
        //Do ClientB countREST
    }
}

public void main(String[] args){
ca = new ClientA();
cb = new ClientB();

callCount(ca);
}

public void callCount(BaseClass o){
     System.out.println("count of "+o.getName()+" is:"+o.countREST());
}
```

Also, you could also use reflection to find the method. However, this is not very clean and tends to use quite a bit more resources.

Comment: But we both know that would not be the _best_ way to do it.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Lol... You're right. Maybe not the *best* way, but it's a way :)